# Pasting a range of cells onto a same size target range with special conditions?

Tags: excel, vba, range, conditional-statements, copy-paste

Thanks for helping me out. I couldn't find a solution to this on the web so here a am :P. I am wondering how to paste a range of values, in this case C6:R371, to another worksheet in the same size. My problem is that I only want to paste  data from the source worksheet into cells that are blank on the target worksheet and not change the values that are already in the range C6:R371 on the target worksheet. Essentially, I have a range of cells that i need to c&p, but i want the macro to only paste values from the range onto the blank cells of the target range. Thank you so much

```
    Range("C6:S371").Select
    Selection.Copy
    wbWest2.Activate
    Dim rng As Range 
    Dim row As Range 
    Dim cell As Range 
    Set rng = Range("D9:S374") 
    For Each row In rng.Rows 
    For Each cell in row.Cells 
    If cell.value = 0 then selection.paste 
    Next cell 
    Next row
```

Comment: What is the top-left cell in the destination range? You've stated they are the same size but not the actual cell address of the destination.

Comment: `D1:S374` is **NOT** the same size as `C6:S371`. Please clarify.

Comment: Ok. You want to set both ranges, not just one. Because they're on different sheets, you want to qualify them otherwise how would computer know which sheet each range is on? The format to qualify is `sheet.range`. Edit: also consider better variable names. `srcRng` is better than simply `rng`.

Comment: Right but your architecture is flawed. Your code is copying an entire range `C6:S371` and trying to paste into a single cell. Edit: I thought you figured it out when you did two loops ^_^; This is the hardest part. I let you think about it some more^^

Comment: OHHH so would it be like the same thing except i define different variables and instead of paste it is copy

Comment: Welp, Jeeped is using arrays which is smarter/faster. Anyways, it was fun engaging you ^_^ You're pretty sharp for a beginner!

Comment: wait but if you did the same thing before hand, the clipboard would just be refreshed again and again running through the source code and when it is done it will only have one value and then copy that one value to all the blank cells no?

Comment: you would have to make if so that it goes back and forth between the worksheets everytime b4 it copies another cell right?

Comment: Logic for nested loops are very tricky... sleep on it^^ It gets easier with practice. Took me years to grasp it...well, I still am XD Edit: yes! you got it. That's why you want to qualify both ranges first.

Comment: haha alright tysm for your help Sir (or Ma'am!) I appreciate your help, you made me learn a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate the two worksheets using [With ... End With statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) so thier cells are the only ones that are considered. The fastest comparison would be bulk loading the two ranges into variant arrays.

```
Sub fill_blanks_from_source()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, aSRCs As Variant, aDSTs As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")     '<~~ source
        aSRCs = .Range("C6:R371").Value2
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")     '<~~ destination
        aDSTs = .Range("D9").Resize(UBound(aSRCs, 1), UBound(aSRCs, 2)).Value2
    End With

    For r = LBound(aDSTs, 1) To UBound(aDSTs, 1)
        For c = LBound(aDSTs, 2) To UBound(aDSTs, 2)
            If Not CBool(Len(aDSTs(r, c))) Then
                aDSTs(r, c) = aSRCs(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("D9").Resize(UBound(aDSTs, 1), UBound(aDSTs, 2)) = aDSTs
    End With

End Sub
```

Once the comparisons have been met and blank values from the destination filled with values from the source, the entire variant array is returned to the destination worksheet.

The ranges will always remain the same size. Once the source values are loaded to the first variant array, the [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) functions are use for all further dimensioning of the destination range expanding from the cell in the top-left corner.

Comment: This is by far the quickest method to evaluate and transfer large blocks of values but remember that formatting is not carried across; only raw values. That can be a good thing or a problem depending upon the individual situation.

Comment: while i ran this code i got an error, in the debugger it highlighted the line If "Not CBool(Len(aDSTs(r, c))) Then"  and says Len(aDSTs(r, c)) = <Type Mismatch>" as well as "aDSTs(r, c) = Error 2015" @Jeeped

Comment: @VbaNoob - Could you look at [this sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/array_Copy.xlsb)? If it runs, perhaps you could determine why the values in the destination are giving you trouble. This is most likely a data problem and hence impossible to diagnose remotely.

Comment: My pleasure. Please mark the checkbox at top left of the answer for Jeeped.

Comment: No. Carrying formulas across is a completely different process.

Comment: is there any way to possibly highlight the cells that are different previously in red? I work for an accounting firm and this is to prevent security fraud so it is easier to catch. Essentially, any number that was previously changed and does not match the current value in the destination cell, i want to highlight the destination cell red so we know to go back and look at what changed in the source sheet that may be fraudulent.

Comment: something like `For r = LBound(aDSTs, 1) To UBound(aDSTs, 1)

For c = LBound(aDSTs, 2) To UBound(aDSTs, 2)
If IsEmpty(aDSTs(r, c)) = True Then
                    aDSTs(r, c) = aSRCs(r, c)
ElseIf aDSTs(r, c) <> aSRCs(r, c) Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D9").Resize(r, c).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ElseIf aDSTs(r, c) = aSRCs(r, c) Then
End If` even though i know this i s wrong

Comment: No, you couldn't use array for this unless you recorded all of the range addresses and changed the color that way. If you need more individual cell control, you should likely switch to examining each cell-by-cell.

Comment: btw, if you need to expand on the requirements beyond what was originally posted, please consider creating a new question. That is [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)'s policy when new requirements are sufficient to invalidate previously correct answers.